# how to pass mvc controller actionresult parameters to angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my app I'm trying to  pass to mvc controller parameters to angular controller. because i want to get data from another api.

**MVC Controller**

```
public ActionResult Hotel(long hotelCode, string Destination)
{ return View(model); }
```

In view i pass model to script. so i can get parameters to angular.

**VIEW**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));</script>
```

**AngulerJS Controller**

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $q, $window, studentService, filterFilter) {
$scope.datax = $window.data;
$scope.saveSubs = function () {
    var sub = {
        Des: $scope.datax.HotelCode,
        DepartureDate: $scope.datax.Des
    };
    var saveSubs = APIService.hotelavailability(sub);
    saveSubs.then(function (d) {
        console.log("Succss");
            $scope.respData = d.data.hotels;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Oops! Something went wrong while saving the data.');
        alert("Oops! Something went wrong while saving the data.");
    });

    };
});
```

Is their any way to call api and bind data to view without passing parameter to angular controller?.

Comment: have you tried to use `ng-init` to set or intialize your data to ng controller

Comment: I think this is a wrong way to do it because of various reasons: 1) you should try to keep the front-end app as separate as possible from back-end app, this will prevent clashes between front-end and back-end teams and be more productive being managed separately based on interfaces, and by totally different stacks; 2) don't try to pass data as a global variable, is polluting global scope and has less meaning; 3) related to (1) you can use task runners or bundlers to switch between scripts which initialize data, that can create angular constants or add HTML into $templateCache; ...continue

Comment: 4) if you need data from server you might as well create a $http call or use a template url that points to the right direction; 5) try to keep your HTML inside your angular templates instead of generating HTML from server-side code, then get the necessary data from server and bind it to your templates, this will allow caching your templates in $templateCache but as well you can use plugins to bundle HTML into JS code in order to cache them and prevent multiple calls; 6) don't call your controller `ctrl` and split your code among multiple modules, components, directives, filters, ...

Comment: actually i want to  get data from hotelbeds api and bind to view. but parameters are in another view. that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable data should be accessible as a global variable, without the need to inject $window.

```
$scope.datax = data;
```

If that feels uncomfortable you should be able to access the window variable directly too:

```
$scope.datax = window.data;
```

Binding directly in the template could cause problems if you ever update that value, as there's no watch set up on global variables outside the scope of your controller.